# PutExtra(String!.String?) is givng error (in android Kotlin), what could be the problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

MainActivity.kt
PutExtra(String!.String?) is givng error (in android Kotlin), what could be the problem?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() 

{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


}
    var name:EditText? = null


fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {

    name = findViewById(R.id.NameInput)
    val intent = Intent(this,BirthdayGreetActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreetActivity.NAME_EXTRA,name)
    startActivity(intent)

}

}
```

Comment: Please post the code and error message as text, not as image.

Comment: Add like this -   intent.putExtra("name",name?.text)

Comment: i figure it out i have not used the kotlin extension in gradle inside dependences

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

when sending data

```
intent.putExtra("name",name)
```

when receiving data

```
val name= intent.getStringExtra("name").toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreetActivity.NAME_EXTRA,name)
```

this line of yours adds NameInput to intent not string. I dont know what your NameInput is but you may try name.text. Maybe if you gave the code of NameInput I might help better.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass whole edittext to another activity; you have to convert text of edittext into string and pass that string to another activity.

```
val nameText = edittext.text.toString().trim()
```

use nameText to pass